# Smack 4.2 does not include jabber:client in outgoing stanzas

Tags: xmpp, smack, prosody-im

I am using Smack 4.2 to implement a fairly basic XMPP chat client. I am using Prosody XMPP server. Prosody is fairly strict about requiring "xmlns=jabber:client" in all incoming stanzas. Smack 4.2 does not include this attribute in its outgoing stanzas. I have tried extending Bind and Session stanzas, and I can make the connection work that way. But, now I am getting into joining rooms, and I really dont want to modify Smack's MUC code so that it can accept a modified Presence message.

Please help!!

Comment: The jabber:client namespace is usually only set in the 'stream' open tag, there is no need to repeat it in every stanza. Also Smack is regularly tested against prosody, including MUC. Could you share some more details? For example: What makes you believe that prosody rejects the stanzas because of the missing namespace? Do you use BOSH by the way?

Comment: @Flow, I am using mod_websocket plugin for Prosody and connecting to Prosody over websocket. I have a home-grown implementation of AbstractXMPPConnection that supports Websocket connections and works fine with Smack 4.2. But, I am wondering if with Smack 4.3, there is a built-in way of using websockets?

Comment: You need to pass the enclosing namespace in toXml() in Smack 4.3. I'd expect passing 'null' would do the trick for you, but it would be very helpful if you could show us the actual code you wrote. I'd be also happy if you would consider upstreaming your websocket code.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why Prosody server requires it, there is nothing about it in official XEP-0045 standard https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#enter

Maybe there is a way to disable it at Prosody side somehow

Answer (score 0):

Smack 4.3 does add xmlns to every outgoing IQ: https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack/blob/master/smack-core/src/main/java/org/jivesoftware/smack/packet/Stanza.java#L518

So that at least solves the xmlns problem.

Comment: The problem here is about Presence, not IQ